# Pgfplots: Tick coords are being ignored

Tags: pgfplots, ticks

Working on a bar chart currently and I cannot seem to get the ticks of the y axis to work correctly. More precisely the `ytick = \empty` (and also `ytick = {0,5,10,15,20}` ) parameter seems to be ignored. Meaning that it just uses the initial `=data` as a value and only shows the ticks of the first plot. On the other hand, adding the parameter `extra y ticks = {5,10,15,20}` for example, works.

```
\begin{figure}
 \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}
 \fbox{
 \vspace*{-100pt}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \centering
  \begin{axis} [
  height=0.4\textheight, width=0.9\textwidth,
  ybar, ymin=0,
  %ytick={5,10,15,20},
  extra y ticks={5,10,15,20},
  tick align = inside,
  legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.1)},
            anchor=north,
            legend columns=-1,
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}
        },
  symbolic x coords={%
    {1},{2},{3},{4},{5}},
  nodes near coords,
  nodes near coords align={vertical},
  ytick=data,
  ]

    \addplot coordinates {
        ({1}, 0)
        ({2}, 1)
        ({3}, 2)
        ({4}, 5)
        ({5}, 2)
    };

    \addplot coordinates {
        ({1}, 1)
        ({2}, 6)
        ({3}, 17)
        ({4}, 10)
        ({5}, 7)
    };

    \legend{Ipsum, Cillum }
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \caption{Lorem}
  \end{figure}
```

Comment: You don't have any `ytick=\empty`. I guess only one `ytick` can be used, so the last one "wins". Unrelated notes: Move `\centering` to before `\begin{tikzpicture}`. What's the point of the `\fbox`?

Comment: Ugh, I guess I got blind again. Thank you, have totally missed the other ytick down there :) The point of the fbox was that it helped me align or position the chart better.

Also you should make that an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `ytick` entries in the options the the `axis`, one right before the `extra y ticks` and one at the end. I guess the last one "wins", so you only get `ytick=data`. The default ticks are 0,5,10,15, which seems like what you want, so there's no need for any adjustments. 
Adding `xtick=data` seems like a good idea as well.

Note also that your `\centering` is in the wrong place, it should be outside the `tikzpicture`. I also removed the `\fbox` and `\vspace`, because I don't think they actually do anything useful here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
  height=0.4\textheight, width=0.9\textwidth,
  ybar, ymin=0,
  tick align = inside,
  legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.1)},
            anchor=north,
            legend columns=-1,
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}
        },
  xtick=data,
  symbolic x coords={%
    {1},{2},{3},{4},{5}},
  nodes near coords,
  nodes near coords align={vertical},
  ]

    \addplot coordinates {
        ({1}, 0)
        ({2}, 1)
        ({3}, 2)
        ({4}, 5)
        ({5}, 2)
    };

    \addplot coordinates {
        ({1}, 1)
        ({2}, 6)
        ({3}, 17)
        ({4}, 10)
        ({5}, 7)
    };

    \legend{Ipsum, Cillum }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Lorem}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```